# Docusign - How to decide signing orders?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Java SDK, embedded signing. I want to have two or three signers, and with specific order. Also, how to prevent one signer to sign someone else's sign tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're specifying the recipients of an Envelope that you're creating/sending, set the `routingOrder` property of each recipient object to an integer to indicate the sequence in which the recipients should sign the Envelope. For example, if an Envelope has 3 recipients and I want them to sign sequentially (one after another), I'd set `routingOrder` to `1` for the recipient who should sign first, `routingOrder` to `2` for the recipient who should sign second, and `routingOrder` to `3` for the recipient who should sign third. Note that if you're using *embedded* signing, then you won't be able to successfully request the signing URL ("Get Recipient View") for a signer until it's his/her turn in the routing order.

Re *how to prevent one signer to sign someone else's sign tab* -- when each recipient accesses the Envelope, he/she will only have access to the tabs (including signature tabs and another other input fields) that were assigned to him/her at the time the Envelope was created -- it works this way by default (you don't have to do anything special to get this behavior).